# Laravel: unit test with click function

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I'm using laravel `5.6` and I'm currently writing tests.

I would like to perform action like this in my unit/feature test

```
$this->actingAs( $user)->visit('/')
                       ->click('my_button');
```

But the click/visit functions are not available in the default tests. They are only available when using `Dusk`

But `Dusk` take more time to run, is it possible to bring back some functions like `click` in the default unit test run by `phpunit`?

I saw that [this package](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing) is "bringing back" thoses functions, but is it needed? Or should I simply run it with `Dusk` to avoid further problem?

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit should be available out of the box with Laravel.

You just run them differently than when you use Dusk.

```
php artisan make:test UserTest
```

Use this to create a new test then use the following:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
/**
 * A basic functional test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->actingAs( $user)->visit('/')
                   ->click('my_button');
}
}
```

Also, check that you have a phpunit.xml setup in your project.

Comment: I did that but when I run the test, phpunit tell me `Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::visit()`

Comment: There is no visit function in 5.4 or above just remembered. If you want to use old functions you can install the browser kit.

Comment: composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing

Comment: Yep. That's why I posted this question. To see other alternative. Is there one? Or should I simply migrate to Dusk?

Comment: Like I say you can use the browser kit & that should bring back "some" old functions, but I would recommend migrating to Dusk as that's currently supported.